# <header> element not floating right nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm not sure why my header element with the nav won't float to the right with "float: right;"

I'm just getting started with html&CSS I was hoping someone could help make my nav bar float to the right. I've looked up a couple of videos and stack overflows but I'm not sure what's wrong I just started by looking up a few things to get started from bootstrap, W3 and some other sites.

my code below

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav {
  float: right 1;
}

header nav ul li a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- <a href="" class="logo" > <img src="images/linkedin_logo.png" alt="Image" height="42" width="42"></a> -->
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `float: right 1;` is a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the Bootraps .row class is adding flex box to the div which in term is blocking the float right css. The float property gets ignored in a flex container.

**From the flexbox specification:**

A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context, except that flex layout is used instead of block layout. so float does not create floating or clearance of flex item.

[image]

remove the .row class and you float style should start work!

Comment: Thank you! Saved me a lot of headache!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `container` element.

```css
*, html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header
{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}


ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

header nav 
{
    float: right;
}

header nav ul li a
{
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;

    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Website Project</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>

      <div class="row">
                    <!-- <a href="" class="logo" > <img src="images/linkedin_logo.png" alt="Image" height="42" width="42"></a> -->
            <nav>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Clients</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
            
</header>


</body>
</html>
```